# tmux inside a remote tmux

Tags: ssh, tmux

What happens if I remote login to a PC start tmux there and from there remote login to another pc and start tmux there?

I did it once, and when dettaching, it dettached from the first tmux.

Is there a way to dettach only from the second one?

Answer (score 4):

This presents an interesting situation. Think of `tmux` as an extra abstraction layer that interprets your keystrokes (among a decent amount of other stuff).

The problem here is that both `tmux` instances are probably configured with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> as the prefix key. This means only the first instance actually catches the prefix command.

To get around this, configure another key combination than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> as the prefix key for either session. In this example, I'll go with configuring <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> as the prefix key for the second machine (but it could be the other way around).

Add the following to your `~/.tmux.conf` on the second machine:

```
# Set prefix key to C-f
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-f
bind C-f send-prefix
```

Now the prefix key on the second machine is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>.

Now, if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and then <kbd>d</kbd>, you detach from the second `tmux` session.

And when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> and then <kbd>d</kbd>, you detach from the first `tmux` session.